Как сделать динамический путь при деплое вместо http://localhost:3000
в returl url: у меня env YOOKASSA_CALLBACK_URL: http://localhost:3000/?paid, как мне сделать так? чтоб этот путь был динамический, то есть при деплое проекта подставлялся путь вместо http://localhost:3000


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

используй файл .env укажи режим запуска
NODE_ENV='development'
или в package.json скриптом
"start": "set NODE_ENV=development&&nodemon index.js",

при деплое указывай production
в коде
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {}
//или
const host = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ?'localhost':'not_localhost'


Яндекс не принимает динамический код к редиректу. Нужно выбрать тот что прописан в настройках кошелька и указать его в env. Или определить в переменной.
